# How can I get message list and details from LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am creating a LinkedIn plugin that helps users to track there messages. For this, I need users messages.

**Is there any feature in Javascript or REST API to get conversation list and messages in LinkedIn?**

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

linkedin is working on this concept:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/communications/messages

> Utilize Messages API to retrieve and send messages to your connections and more! API is coming soon.

Comment: it says "Something went wrong. We can't seem to find that page", Do you have any idea on different documentation.. I am not able to find the relevant documentation

Comment: as Linkedin is now part of the Microsoft group, you will need to look at the new api.

Comment: Yes, I have verified but didn't find any solution